# Examining Cointegration Before or After Deseasonalizing

Tags: r, econometrics, stationarity, vector-autoregression, seasonality

I am trying to build a VAR model with two time series, one of which is I(0) and one of which is I(1). I originally tested these for cointegration with a Johansen Test and found them cointegrated with rank r=2 and thought a VEC model was going to be appropriate. But I realized that even testing them for cointegration was probably not valid, and that although there seem to be some conflicting opinions, if I'm dealing with one stationary time series and one nonstationary time series I should just estimate a VAR model.

So this is what I did, including a seasonal component in the model specifications (using VAR() in R) since I'm using weekly data that exhibits strong seasonality.

Here's the issue: In order to use a specific package on R I had to re-estimate my VAR model, this time by deseasonalizing the data on the front end. When I did this and tested for stationarity again, *both of the series were nonstationary*. So once deseasonalized, I have to I(1) series, leading me to wonder if I should be testing them for cointegration and then using a VEC model after all.

So this is my question: do I use the VAR model, because the original data series are not cointegrated (one stationary, one not), or should I test for cointegration of the deseasonalized series and build a VEC model for them? I have spent a lot of time looking for an answer and haven't been able to find anything about this specific issue.

Sorry if this is a confusing question. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I realize this was not clear originally: I constructed the VAR model using the stationary series and the *first difference of the non-stationary series*, I did not throw a non-stationary series directly into a VAR model.

Comment: Regarding *there seem to be some conflicting opinions*, I wonder where you found a suggestion of putting an I(0) and I(1) as is into a VAR model?

Comment: Sorry, I realize this was unclear in my original post -- I took the first difference of the I(1) series before constructing the VAR model.  So it was made with two stationary series, I didn't throw one stationary series and one non-stationary series into the model.

Comment: Great, this is clear now!